# how to change title of ... more navigation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have an interface laid out in storyboard, and one of my controllers gets pushed into the ... **More... section of the tab bar controller**. I cannot seem to find a way to set it's navigation item's title. It is set up in the storyboard, but does not appear.

Here's the structure Tabbar > relationship to Navigation controller> relationship to view controller

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"DOES NOT WORK";

    UINavigationBar *moreNavigationBar = self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController. navigationBar;
    moreNavigationBar.topItem.title = @"SETS THE BACK BUTTON TITLE";
```

**What do I need to do to set text in the empty space on the attached screenshot?**

[image: Tab bar more item title]

Comment: Is the above code in view did Load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have custom code inside the tab bar that hides the title, you just have to change the `title` property of the *view controller* being displayed. That can easily be done inside the storyboard editor.

[image: Property edition]

Comment: Thank you, I figured out that my controller was subclassing another one and that one incorrectly reset the navbar title to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this programmatically you can just add the following in your `viewDidLoad` of `viewController` as,

```
self.title = @"title goes here";
```